# How to use PUT method in WP8 using WebClient()

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, webclient, put

I'm able to GET and POST data using Webclient, but I need to know how to PUT/Update data into the server..

MY code that I tryed with PUT methos in WebClient..

```
string serviceURL = REST_URI + servicePath;
Uri URI = new Uri(serviceURL);
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers["ContentType"] = "application/json";
webClient.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
webClient.UploadStringCompleted += this.updationCompleted;
webClient.UploadStringAsync(URI, "PUT", organizationDetails);



private void updationCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Success..");
        MessageBox.Show(e.Result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);//i'm getting error here as check for inner exception..
    }
```

My Exception..

[image]
Can anyone help me over this problem

My Inner Exception Message..

[image]

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: check my post i had updated..

Comment: post your InnerException too.

Comment: sorry i don't know how to retrieve it.. i'm new to WP8

Comment: Write `string exp = ex.StackTrace`and post the stack trace in question.

Comment: @farokemoahmed simply put a breakpoint inside `catch` and check what's in `ex.InnerException`

Comment: Plz check my post for inner exception.. i had updated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem from your side:

```
The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
```

It looks like there is no such available method on server side or it doesn't accept `PUT`.

Make sure that you're using correct uri, http verb and content type.